# Building a Citation Network to Analyze in R

Tags: r, social-network-analysis, data-formats

I am working on network analysis project at one of our Nation's Service Academies, and I need a little help.

As a starting point, we are looking at a citation network that we build by using the keyword, "Network Analysis", for peer reviewed articles only in Web of Science. We took the top 50 results, and looked at the articles to which those cited and built a citation network.  It outputs the information in Bibtex, Tab-Delimited, HTML, Plain Text, End Note, and a few others.

Here is my question:

- What is the best way to create a citation network?

We have these formats, but it is not usable yet.  Ideally, we would have a matrix with article names on the x and y, and binary numbers for the
    connections.
[image: sample data]

Comment: Welcome to the site! Do you have any sample data? so that can suggest you better.

Comment: @Toros91 We downloaded a tab-delimited list of 200 reference using a keyword, and made a binary matrix for overlap or connections.  Should we use the same set of articles in both the x and y to see if they cite each other?  Instead we looked at each article's cited references and tried to find the connections.  We had to do the latter by hand.  Does this make sense and if so, is there a faster way to do it.

Comment: what does the data that stores the articles and their list of citations look like?

Comment: It is all in plain text form, and I use the text import wizard in excel to filter and separate the results.  I haven't used the bibtex format much, but the picture above shows the main piece to be the title of the article.  What other formats be of more use?

Comment: @JosephBosse .txt is probably fine. One possibility is if your data is structured similar to the form `articlename, source1, source2, source3,..`, you could read in the data and group using each source as a key, generating an output of `{'source1':['article1', 'article2']..}`: preferably using Python, if you are open to using a language other than R.  From there, you could graph the connections using Python tools such as `matplotlib` or `NetworkX`. If possible, could you post a sample of your article and citation data?

Answer (score 2):

I don't understand if you want to build a network of authors who cite each other, or a network of papers who cite other papers (which would be a much sparser network because the coauthorship relationships won't show up as edges).

I would follow a strategy similar to this one (off the top of my head):

1. Assign ids to your papers
2. Build 2 csv files : papers.csv, citations.csv
3. read in 2-col csv file "paper.csv" as a two-column data frame:  col1: paper_id, col2: title
4. read in 2-col csv file "citations.csv" as a two-column data frame:  col1: paper_id, col2: cites_id,

With R's [igraph](https://github.com/igraph/igraph/) package, you can construct a  network pg (for papers_graph) 
with (pseudocode)

`pg <- igraph::graph_from_data_frame(citations)`

Then you assign "vertex attributes" to the nodes in the network:

```
pg <- set_vertex_attribute(pg, "title", value= papers) 
# same as:  V(pg)$title <- papers$title
```

(and possibly many other attributes)

Then you can use igraph's many functions (~200) to analyze the network.

For visualizations, you plot the ids, and use a diagram type which gives you the title when you move the mouse over / click on the node symbol (which is labeled only with the id to save screen space). You can use other design elements such as coloring the nodes by release year for instance).

Comment: This is the update with our pseudocode, tell me your thoughts

Answer (score 1):

Parse an edgelist out of your data, load it into a dataframe with two columns (source, target), then feed that to [`igraph::graph_from_data_frame`](http://igraph.org/r/doc/graph_from_data_frame.html)

Comment: I understand that piece if I were looking at first order data, but I am trying to look at the base 200 reference's citations, or more simply, finding connections between my base articles and all the citation of the base articles in a effort to detect the echo effect.

Comment: The first step is going to be loading your data into a graph object, which is what I showed you how to do. I'm not sure what you mean by "base 200 reference's citations", but you'll probably find igraph's induced subgraphing, node similarity metrics (e.g. cocitation, bibliographic index) and community detection functions useful. But you didn't ask how to analyze your data, you asked how to construct the network (which you're going to need to do anyway).

Comment: This is the update, tell me your thoughts: https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/27082/echo-effect-metric-network

Answer (score 1):

If I understand it correctly, the matrix which was shown(snapshot) was actually generated manually. I'm I correct?, If yes, then the process which you have done is right. For generating the Graphs/Social Network you need to transform the data into **Source and Edges**(Weights too if possible but not mandatory). I think you already have it ready in that format, by which I mean you where saying that both `x and y` to be **Source**/words and **Edges** as connections (0 or 1).

If considering that the data is ready, then next question is

1. Are you looking just for Visualizing and deriving insights?

   or
2. Do you want to do some analysis on the data to find communities and see
   a how are they distributed/spread within themselves or determine which is a key player etc.

Now answer with respect to question-1, you have tool named Gephi, which can give you amusing visualizations. For example you can see the [Link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FLiv3xnEepw). Can use Tableau, have done something similar to this using Tableau and R.

[image: Airport Connections]

With respect to question-2, you can use different algorithms under [igraph](https://www.r-bloggers.com/summary-of-community-detection-algorithms-in-igraph-0-6/) package in R and get some output. Use different visualization tool for getting insights from the outcome. The link attached gives you idea about different algorithms available in R for performing community detection.

Finally to answer the question for making the data into the sample shown by you, should be done manually. Just to let you know, generally in the life-cycle of any analytics project, It is very likely to spend most of the time in Data Preparation phase(30-50% of time) just to make sure that the data is ready, ignore this if you know this before. I mean, there is no shortcut/easy path for for preparing the data.

Please go through this [Link](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/26454/use-cases-for-graph-algorithms-and-graph-data-structures-in-finance-and-banking/26465#26465), to know how network analysis would help us in getting good insights but it is respective to finance industry. It might help you to derive similar insights.

This [Link](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/key-player-community-detection-using-graph-theory-imdb-joshua-johnson/), would help you to understand the scope of Network Analysis. This analysis was done by one of my friend during our course work. I was really amused by the insight which he could derive from the analysis. Probably you could also perform something similar. Just sharing this link for your reference.